# How to split wpf xaml page into more maintainable small parts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a wpf application and the main page consist of a sidebar a header and a content area where the rest of the app will be displayed, since i come for an angular background can i split the sidebar and the header and the content area into small maintainable components and how can it be achieved

Comment: You may create several [UserControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: The purpose of WPF `UserControl` is splitting a huge page of window into several parts. By the way, the purpose of `Control` or `ContentControl` which is also called Custom Control is creating more reusable UI parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Solution Explorer, right click on your project and add a new UserControl. Call it for example "FeatureView". In that UserControl, insert a textblock with a dummy text like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp10.FeatureView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="This is my FeatureView UserControl"/>
</Grid>
```

Then, in your MainWindow load it in the following way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:FeatureView/>

</Grid>
```

You should be able to see your dummy text. You can expand this with more UserControls.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the areas into user controls:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-user-control-to-the-start-page?view=vs-2017

A nice way of managing this is to use Prism Regions, see:

https://rohiton.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/understanding-prism-part-2-regions/